# Azure Pipeline | Create linear dependency between the two

Tags: azure, databricks, pipeline

There are two pipelines. The second pipeline should trigger after the first one is completed.
The second pipeline needs parameter which is an id received from the first job.

I checked webhook and triggers but there is no option to pass parameters to the job. Is there a way to create dependency as well pass parameters to a pipeline?

Comment: which pipeline you are using?

Comment: It is an Azure Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

To create a dependency between your two pipelines, you can create a pipeline resource trigger for your second pipeline to make it run automatically whenever the first pipeline completes. eg:

```yaml
# First pipeline
steps:
- bash: echo "The first pipeline runs first"
```

```yaml
# Second pipeline
# We are setting up a pipeline resource that references the first pipeline
# pipeline and setting up a pipeline completion trigger so that our second
# pipeline runs when a run of the first pipeline completes
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: firstPipeline # Name of the pipeline resource.
    source: first-pipeline # The name of the pipeline referenced by this pipeline resource.
    project: ProjectName # Required only if the source pipeline is in another project
    trigger: true # Run second pipeline when any run of first pipeline completes

steps:
- bash: echo "second pipeline runs after first pipeline completes"
```

See [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops) for more details.

For your second question of passing a variable from one pipeline to the next, the best solution that I have found is by referencing and updating variables in a pipeline variable group. See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

For example:

```yaml
# First pipeline 
# As a task in the first pipeline, update any pipeline 
# variables that other pipelines will need

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Update variable
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: azure-sub-arm
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az pipelines variable-group variable update --group-id <<id>> --name <<variable_name>> --value <<new_value>>
```